# How to reduce repetition for this case?

Tags: c#, generics, interface, dry

In C# I have two classes of the form A, A where A is a customised IEnumerable over reference types and B, C are reference types that inherit from a class D. There is a property named P that exists on B, C but not D, and it would be inappropriate to add it to D as other classes inheriting from D shouldn't have P. I have instances b, c of A, A for which I need to do the following for constants x, y of the same type as P:

```
b.Where(v => v.P == x).ForEach(v => v.P = y);
c.Where(v => v.P == x).ForEach(v => v.P = y);
```

This code works, but how can I avoid repetition viz. the DRY principle?

My own efforts have encountered three major difficulties:

1. Since P doesn't exist on D one cannot simply create a function that works on instances of D and cast viz. b.Select(v => (D)v).
2. Since P doesn't exist on generic types, the compiler won't tolerate the obvious way to run this logic with a generic T.
3. Since A only takes T where class, a generic using A complains that T needs to be a reference type.

I'm especially interested in solutions that create a generic method on a new interface from which B, C can inherit, as I've been advised this approach should be possible.

Comment: Please add the code to define your classes A, B, C and D.

Comment: I can't do that; it's proprietary. In any case, it would be a lot of code.

Comment: You have described your example. Describe it in code.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you want to solve a problem which doesn't exist. It will be much simpler with your class definition, but you can do something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x = 1;
        int y = 2;

        var b = new MyCustomList<B>();

        b.Foo(v => v.P == x, n => n.P = y);
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static void Foo<T>(this IFoo<T> @this, Func<T, bool> predicate, Action<T> action) => @this.Where(predicate).ToList().ForEach(action);
}

public interface IFoo<T> : IList<T>  { }

class MyCustomList<T> : List<T>, IFoo<T>  { }

class B
{
    public int P { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Using `ToList()`in order to make use of `ForEach(...)` makes me shiver. Why not use a `foreach` loop instead? Comes with LazyEvaluation and doesnt allocate anny additional memory (array of the ToList)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want something similar to this:

```
public interface IHasPropertyP { Foo P { get; } }
public class B: D, IHasPropertyP { ... }
public class C: D, IHasPropertyP { ... }

List<D> dees = ... //I don't care if the type of the items is B, C or D
var onlyThoseWhoHavePropertyP = dees.OfType<IHasPropertyP>();
onlyThoseWhoHavePropertyP.Where(v => v.P == x).{whatever needs to be done...}
```

Answer (score 0):

> This code works, but how can I avoid repetition viz. the DRY principle?

You *can* remove this repetition - there are at least two ways I can think of - but consider what it gains you here. The operation you want to carry out is "Set P to Y on those objects where it is X" - this is about as simple as it gets, and having two parallel lines next to each other makes it completely clear in a way that a DRYer solution doesn't.

The two ways I can think of have been covered in other answers, but briefly:

1. create a common interface `IHaveAPropertyP` which `B` and `C` are then made to implement. Requires a code change on `B` and `C`
2. have a method that is passed an object of arbitrary type, along with methods for `get`ting and `set`ing a property `P` on objects of that type.

Either way, **there will still be two very similar lines of code next to each other** - given this, why complicate matters?